# Align avatar center in Material UI Chip

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I want this icon to show up in the middle of the [Material UI chip](https://material-ui.com/components/chips/), nice and centered.  Right now there's a weird whitespace next to it:

[image]

```js
<Chip
  avatar={<LinkAvatarImage socialTypeId={link.socialTypeId} />}
  size="small"
  variant="outlined" 
/>
```

```
export function LinkAvatarImage({ socialTypeId } : { socialTypeId: number }) {
  if (socialTypeId === socialTypes.PERSONAL_WEBSITE) {
    return <WebIcon />;
  }
...
```

I don't know how to tweak Material UI's Chip to do so.

I tried this but no luck:

```
export const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    chip: {
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
    }
  }),
);
```

```js
const classes = useStyles();

<Chip
  avatar={<LinkAvatarImage socialTypeId={link.socialTypeId} />}
  size="small"
  classes={classes.chip}
  variant="outlined" 
/>
```

but I also don't see a way to inject a custom style via the props on Chip.  There doesn't seem to be a property to let me do that in the first place.  I *think* there's a classes prop but I don't understand how to set that in this case.

Answer (score 3):

use `display: flex`

```
export const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    chip: {
      display: 'flex',
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
    }
  }),
);

const classes = useStyles();

<Chip
  avatar={<LinkAvatarImage socialTypeId={link.socialTypeId} />}
  size="small"
  classes={classes.chip}
  variant="outlined" 
/>
```

Comment: no I've already tried this, it does not work.  You also didn't show how to wire it up via the props on the Chip itself

Comment: add display: flex;. Without this align-items: center and justify-content: center won't work.

Comment: I don't know what you just said.  You didn't read anything I just said did you

Answer (score 1):

@Techuila (thanks!) helped me in a bit of the direction.  Here is what worked for me:

```js
<Chip
  ...
  style={{
    width: '40px',
    height: '30px',
    paddingLeft: '15px',
    margin: '5px'
   }}
/>
```

it's an inline style but at this point who cares, it works.

Comment: well normally I'm a perfectionist.  If you were to TDD with me on a codebase, I'd be very strict on clean code :P.  I just don't really give as much of a shiz about styles, one off hack is ok as long as it's not done too many times and you revisit it to try to improve it later.

Comment: how would this inline style break TDD principles?

Answer (score 1):

There are *padding-left* and *padding-right* CSS settings inside the `MuiChip-label` style definition that cause that unwanted effect.

To center the avatar (or an icon) you can try to use the `sx` syntax to set that *padding* value to 0.

```
<Chip
  avatar={<LinkAvatarImage socialTypeId={link.socialTypeId} />}
  size="small"
  variant="outlined"
  sx={{'& .MuiChip-label': {padding: 0}}}
/>
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem too, my workaround is I added a style on my own css file that selects the MuiChip-icon.

App.css

```
.MuiChip-avatar {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: -6px;
}
```

I also think that I missed something but for now I still use this solution.

Comment: ok but how did you reference it from the Chip, how did you wire that up to props on the chip to reference that class?

Comment: I tried this via adding `className` prop and it did not work.  It actually messed it all up and made the outline overlap the icons

Comment: Also when you override Mui styles like that you lose the rest of the theme and it gets all messed up

Comment: @PositiveGuy If you put your ```<LinkAvatarImage socialTypeId={link.socialTypeId} />``` on the avatar prop, then it should have a div container with .MuiChip-avatar class. So all you have to do is to override that class style on your css file by adding the style mentioned above, no need to wire it on your chip via className coz the classname already exists, we just have edit the style of the class. There you can adjust the style of the avatar more freely, this is just a work around tho.

Comment: If you want to change the style only for a selected chips, then just add a new class to your chip and define the style on your css. In that way, you wouldn't have to worry other theme styles overriding.